# Icon Overlay hover over the image

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to show a plus icon in the middle of the image on hover. It does not show as expected.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-danths?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

Can someone prompt me what I did wrong.

Comment: try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jsrvky?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.